Timeout and execution issues with published geoprocessing service in ArcGIS Server
I am running into issues executing a geoprocessing service published on ArcGIS Server. The service works correctly when tested locally in ArcGIS Pro as a toolbox, but it fails when executed via the REST API. Specifically:
1. Service Setup:

The service is published as a geoprocessing tool (Script.GPServer) on ArcGIS Server.
The output of the service (a zipped geodatabase) is correctly written to the server's output directory (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/geodatabases).
The map service is correctly set up with data that is able to be downloaded.
I can access the output file via a direct URL. Below is an output zipped geodatabase that I produced in my testbed ArcGIS Pro toolbox. This was accessible for download by doing the follow. See example:

 https://myArcGISServerIPAddress:6443/arcgis/rest/directories/geodatabases/clipped_data_1733784699.gdb.zip.

2. Execution Attempt:

I am trying to execute the service via its REST API /execute endpoint
with parameters in the query string. Example:


https://myArcGISServerIPAddress:6443/arcgis/rest/services/Script/GPServer/clip/execute?utmE=500000&utmN=4500000&utmZone=16&utmHemisphere=N&width=1000&height=1000&f=json


When I do this, I receive the following JSON error:

{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Error performing execute operation",
        "details": []
    }
}

3. Error Details:

In the ArcGIS Server logs, I see repeated TimeoutException errors:

SEVERE: Processing request took longer than the usage timeout for service 'Script.GPServer'. Server request timed out.


I have already tested and verified that the server can access the
output directory and that the output is being generated successfully
when tested locally.

4. Configuration Details:

I have adjusted the service's Maximum Usage Time in ArcGIS Server
Manager, but the error persists.
The service is synchronous and uses an HTTP POST request to process
data and return output.
I have confirmed there are no network or directory permission issues,
and the server has inbound firewall rules set for ports 6443 and 80.

5. What the Script Does:

The script takes bounding box parameters (utmE, utmN, utmZone,
utmHemisphere, width, height) and creates an area of interest (AOI)
polygon in UTM coordinates.
It clips data layers from a MapService and standalone tables that
intersect the AOI, saving them to a temporary geodatabase.
It reprojects the clipped features and rasters to a specified
coordinate system (e.g., WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_17N).
The output geodatabase is saved to the server's output directory,
zipped, and made available for download through a public URL.

Question:
What could be causing the geoprocessing service to timeout when executed via the REST API, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve this issue? Is there anything specific to ArcGIS Server geoprocessing services, REST execution, or server configuration that I might be overlooking?

You had a tag for Python but have presented no code nor mentioned Python in the body of your question so removed it.

This doesn't seem like it ought to be a synchronous service.  How long does it take to run? I would make a batch job, and poll the service for completion rather than depending on the processing to complete before client timeout.

Any more useful messages in the server log if you change the log level to, VERBOSE or DEBUG?
